# JAX-WS: Using argument in method from another class annotation

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am creating a web service for work. I am breaking it down into 3 separate Maven projects:

- **SOA** (stores the request and response objects used in web methods)
- **Services** (this stores the classes that actually do the processing of the data)
- **WebServices** (This stores the endpoint interface and generated jaxws folder)

In the **SOA** project, I have a simple POJO that is used to pass in the needed values to the web method

```
public class RequestObject {
    private String firstName = null;
    private String lastName = null;

    // Setters and Getters below...
}
```

Then I try to reference this class in the **WebServices** project. I include the **SOA** generated JAR as a dependency in Maven. This does work and pulls in the files correctly.

*Interface*:

```
@WebService
public interface WebServiceInf {
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="WebMethodResult")
    String createSomething(@WebParam(name="requestObject")RequestObject request);
}
```

*Web Service*:

```
import com.mine.data.RequestObject;

@WebServiceInterface(endpointInterface="com.mine.WebServiceInf")
public class WebServiceImpl implements WebServiceInf {
    @Override
    public String createSomething(RequestObject request) {
        return "I was created!";
    }
}
```

The issue I am running into is when I use the **wsgen** tool. It works fine if I place the *RequestObject* inside the **WebService** project. But, once I placed that class into the **SOA** project, it throws the following error:

```
Problem encountered during annotation processing; see stacktrace below for more information. java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.isLegalType(WebServiceVisitor.java:770)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.isLegalParameter(WebServiceVisitor.java:670)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.isLegalMethod(WebServiceVisitor.java:637)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.methodsAreLegal(WebServiceVisitor.java:575)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.isLegalSEI(WebServiceVisitor.java:567)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.shouldProcessWebService(WebServiceVisitor.java:300)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.visitInterfaceDeclaration(WebServiceVisitor.java:94)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.mirror.declaration.InterfaceDeclarationImpl.accept(InterfaceDeclarationImpl.java:32)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.inspectEndpointInterface(WebServiceVisitor.java:395)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.visitClassDeclaration(WebServiceVisitor.java:128)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.mirror.declaration.ClassDeclarationImpl.accept(ClassDeclarationImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.buildModel(WebServiceAP.java:315)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.process(WebServiceAP.java:256)
        at com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessors$CompositeAnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessors.java:60)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.comp.Apt.main(Apt.java:454)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:258)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:1102)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:964)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.processing(Main.java:95)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:85)
        at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:67)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.buildModel(WsgenTool.java:204)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.run(WsgenTool.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:105)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsGen.main(WsGen.java:41) error: compilation failed, errors should have been reported
```

So this looks like I need a certain annotation to tell the **WebService** project that the *RequestObject* is in another project/JAR.

What annotation would I use to do this? Thank you so very much for the help!

**UPDATE**

This is how I am calling the **wsgen**. I am executing this command from the **WebServices** root folder

```
wsgen -keep -cp target/classes/ -s src/main/java -d target/classes/ com.mine.WebServiceImpl
```

Comment: I have a feeling this might have to do with the @WebParam annotation, but I was not sure

Comment: Is the SOA project is a dependency for the WebService project?

Comment: @Pace: Yes. In the Maven POM, I include the SOA project as a dependency in there.

Comment: I've done this before so it should be possible.  However, I am also pretty sure that error indicates that wsgen encountered a class not on the classpath at compile time.  Are you using the default scope for the SOA dependency?

Comment: I am going to update this question with how I am running the wsgen and perhaps that will help. I am betting that is the issue now, but now sure how I can make wsgen point to two classpaths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classpath is pointing at target/classes.  Maven will put all compiled classes for the **current module** in that folder.  That explains why wsgen only finds the class when it is in the local module.  There is a [jax-ws maven plugin](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/) that will setup the classpath for you.  This would be the easiest approach in my mind.  Essentially what you want is...

```
wsgen -keep -cp target/classes:dependency1.jar:dependency2.jar:etc. -s src/main/java -d target/classes com.mine.WebServiceImpl
```